# auth_setting error coming while exporting Products to Channel engine

Tags: python

I am getting the following error while exporting product to channel engine using api-client-python :

> Traceback:
>
> ```
> File "api-client-python/swagger_client/api_client.py", line 512, in update_params_for_auth
> querys.append((auth_setting['key'], auth_setting['value']))
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
> ```

I have used following request to create a new product:

```
products = [swagger_client.MerchantProductRequest()] api_response =
    api_instance.product_create(products)
```